# get file object using full path

Tags: javascript, html

is there a way to get a file object using the directory full path of the file itself? this piece of code wont work:

```
var file1 = new File("D:\\path\\to\\file\\file.txt");
```

I need to get the file object since I have a function that has a file object as its parameter.

bryan

Comment: no. You can't access user's system file  through js in a browser. You can however ask him to select it via an `<input type="file">` element

Answer (score 4):

That would be very tragic if browsers could suddenly start accessing users' file systems without their permission.

I would suggest using `<input type="file">`. This way the user chooses which file they will allow the browser to access.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use: `<input type="file" id="fileUpload">` and get the file name using

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    console.log(this.files[0])
});
```